# Portfolio optimization using ROI

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, quantitative-finance, r-portfolioanalytics

I would like to use the ROI solver to optimize a portfolio of stocks. However, when I try to optimize the portfolio I get an error saying that the number of assets in the beginning weights is less than the returns. I have left the code and the error .

```
library(quantmod)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ROI)

#vector of stocks in my portfolio  of 
tickers <- c("GS", "AAPL", "AMZN", "GM", "CBRL", "NVDA", "AMAT", "NKE","CSCO","SBUX","TLT")
#bind porfolio prices 
portfolioPrices <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers) {
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                           getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,4])
}


#portfolio returns
portfolioReturns <- na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrices))
print(portfolioReturns)
portf <- portfolio.spec(colnames(portfolioReturns.2))
portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="weight_sum", min_sum=.99, max_sum=1.01)
portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="box", min=.02, max=.60) 
portf<-add.constraint(portf,type="transation_cost", ptc=.001)
portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="return", name="mean")
portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")
portf<-add.objective(portfolio = p, type="risk", name="ES", 
                     arguments=list(p=0.925, clean="boudt"))


#optimize portfolio using the "DEoptim solver"
optPort <- optimize.portfolio(portfolioReturns, portf, optimize_method = "ROI", trace=TRUE)
extractWeights(optPort)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Warning message:
>   In Return.portfolio(portfolioReturns, weights = extractWeights(opt_rebal)) :
>     number of assets in beginning_weights is less than number of columns in returns, so subsetting returns.

Comment: I edited my question why is it still on hold . I really need help here can you guys  give me a little bit of leeway here

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Your code should still run